# How to fix result of docker exec (python's docker library)?

Tags: python, docker

I am using python library called **docker** in order to interact with containers. I am trying to pass stdin into my container via pipe (command I am executing looks like this `f'echo "{stdin}" | time -f "%e" {execution_command}'`), but as a result i get, for instance, this: `ExecResult(exit_code=0, output=b'3 4 | time -f %e python tmp/python_script.py\n')`.

For some reason instead of executing *python_script.py*, it simply returns command itself. However, if I execute the same command inside DockerDesktop, I will get correct output.
[Screenshot of DockerDesktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRVGC.png)

Full, but simplified code that I use looks loke this:

```py
code_execution_command = f'echo "3 4" | time -f "%e" tmp/python_script.py'
self._container.exec_run(cmd=code_execution_command, stdin=True)
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't normally be using `docker exec`.  From another program, how would you "go inside" your running Python program to interact with it?  A better approach would be to make a network connection, or if you absolutely must (there are major security and portability concerns) you could launch a new container, but you shouldn't normally need debugging-type commands like `docker exec`.

Comment: There is no need for other programs to interact with python program I am trying to start. It's pretty specific case. I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `exec_run` does not run a shell; so, you cannot use shell facilities like pipes or shell builtins like `time`. Maybe try

```
self._container.exec_run(
    cmd=f"sh -c '{code_execution_command}'",
    stdin=True)
```

(though I don't see how `stdin=True` makes sense here, either. And, you can certainly remove the final `\n` from the command).